# VIA annotation tool json output file for UNET

Tags: image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I would like to know how to use VIA (VGG annotation tool) for generating Binary masks for Unet architecture to work.

I generated the JSON file, after manually annotating the objects in an image. I would like to use UNET for doing image segmentation task after annotating. As my input will be the original image and ground truth image.
Ground truth image which is binary masking image, which can be generated after annotating. I am currently stuck, on how to generate binary  masking image, from VIA JSON annotated file. Kindly advice.

Thanks

Comment: Few relevant links are: 1) https://medium.com/@dataturks/converting-polygon-bounded-boxes-in-the-dataturks-json-format-to-mask-images-f747b7ba921c 2) https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme/blob/master/labelme/cli/json_to_dataset.py#L33

Comment: Hi, Thank you for sharing the links. I was able to get the ground truth binary mapping from json file, with the help of mrcnn (matterport Mask RCNN) visualize.py file.

Comment: How did you get it using visualize.py. Could you elaborate please ?? @GuruprasadhSwaminathan

Comment: @monica, I have uploaded my changes into Github,you can use it as a template. Kindly let me know if you have any issue in the steps mentioned in Github.  Please find the link: https://github.com/Guruprasadh2509/Ground-Truth-Binary-Masking-

Comment: @GuruprasadhSwaminathan. Hey, thank you for responding. I have followed all your steps and during the final step, when I was trying to execute the .ipynb file I keep getting this error: "Unreadable Notebook: NotJSONError('Notebook does not appear to be JSON: \'{\\n "cells": [\\n {\\n "cell_type": "m...',)" Can you help me out please.

Comment: @monica, I tried to download from my  github repo, I was able to run. I am sharing my colab ipynb file link. can you check this out? https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Id1shhlTLJBMHO9L7BVNcELbgdNufmvX                        In case if you have any issue in executing, you can copy the code cell by cell and modify the configurations accordingly and execute it.

Comment: @GuruprasadhSwaminathan. Can you tell me how you annotated your images if you don't mind, like how many classes, format you saved, version used etc. I think my json file format is different.

Comment: @monica, Sure! please find my response below:classes:binary classification, format-Json, version:1.0.6. I referred  this link  https://towardsdatascience.com/cnn-application-detecting-car-exterior-damage-full-implementable-code-1b205e3cb48c for getting info on how to annotate the images using VIA. They have used version 1.0.6.

Comment: @GuruprasadhSwaminathan. Thank you. I will follow this. what do you mean by binary classification ? Is it like 1)actual object in foreground and 2)background or are they two different objects ? Also, if it is the second case, did you have those two objects in every picture ?

Comment: @monica, yeah its background and foreground. I was trying to do semantic segmentation using U-Net. Background I m having multiple objects. In ground truth image, we will have two unique values 0's and 1's. 1 represents the annotated object which is foreground and 0(rest of the objects) will be background.

Comment: @GuruprasadhSwaminathan. Right, the code worked and i even got the masked images. But I got this error at the end. "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\devim\Mask2\KittiSeg\Ground-Truth-Binary-Masking--master\untitled.py", line 71, in <module>
    a[a==30]=0
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment" This is related to what you said. 0's and 1's. For my data, i only have one class (detour sign). i didn't name the background but instead some images have 2 detour signs then i added one more class which says detour again. I dont know whats causing that error

Comment: @monica, can you check the unique value of pixel values, after you read the image?I am guessing value 30 is not present in the pixel values. Hence that error came, just a guess.  I am curious to know about the method you are trying to use here. For Semantic segmentation, just foreground objects together alone can be segmented. Can you show me the annotated images of detour sign if possible, so that I can check some thing on this and tell you.

Comment: @GuruprasadhSwaminathan. I added this line and it says "unique pixel values [None]" and resulted in same error. I have changed the images to png. I have added my json file here but it seems like someone has deleted that post and is not letting me add again.